# in Django, can I use a class only to group functions?

Tags: python, django

I am creating an application using Django. The application has user registration and login functionality.

I have three functions related to user authentication as of now, login, registration, and email_check (which is called when the user types email address to see if it is available). I was trying to group these functions under a class for better organisation and easy accessibility.

So I wrote a class and function like so:

```
class user_auth:
    def check_email(email):
        with connection.cursor() as conn:
            conn.execute('select count(*) from user_info where email = %s', [email])
            row = conn.fetchall()
        response = bool(row[0][0])
        return(response)
```

However, when I do this, I get a pylint error saying `Method should have "self" as the first argument`.

If I save this and call it as `user_auth.check_email('abc@xyz.com')`, it works just fine. But if I add self as the first argument, it stops working.

Am I using classes in an incorrect way? If yes, what is a better way to create a group of functions like this which can be easily imported using a single statement in other files?

Comment: Unlike in some other languages that require classes for code, it is not a typical Python pattern to group functions in classes. You can just use a module for it.

Comment: create a module, call it whatever, usually I call it `utils.py`

Comment: How do you deal with it when utils.py starts to get very long? I already have a separate file, but it was getting rather long. So I thought I'll use classes to group the functions so that it's easy to manage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comments said, you could use a module for it.

Otherwise if you want to group them inside a class you just need to use the `staticmethod` or `classmethod` decorator.

Example:

```py
class user_auth:
    @classmethod
    def check_email(cls, email):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def static_check_email(email):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks. using `@staticmethod` gets rid of the pylint error